# EF7 migration generator is ignoring context parameter

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have recently migrated my EF7 project from DotNet Core 1.0.0 to Version 1.1.0, now I have trouble with creating the database migrations.

In my project I have multiple contexts, the tool dotnet-ef is providing a command line parameter to distinct between these contexts in order to create a separate migration for each context.

When I try to create the migrations for the context "AuditLogContext" with the command

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --context 'Some.Namespace.AuditLogContext' --output-dir './Migrations/AuditLogMigrations'
```

then it fails, telling me

> The name 'Initial' is used by an existing migration.

when I'm trying to create the migration with another name, say *Initial2*, the migration get created but for the wrong context.

In the folder

> ./Migrations/AuditLogMigrations

are new files named

> 20170212122451_Initial2.cs
>
> 20170212122451_Initial2.Designer.cs
>
> CoreContextModelSnapshot.cs

I expect the file **AuditLogContextModelSnapshot.cs** instead.

Does anybody have solved this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this problem.

I have multiple contexts in my project, every context expects parameters. So migrations builder expects a factory for every context.

In my case one class, implements all factories, now there is a bug that the concrete order of the interfaces is used to determine which migrations are created.

```
public class Program : IDbContextFactory<CoreContext>, IDbContextFactory<AuditLogContext>, IDbContextFactory<LockContext>
```

This snippet will create migrations for the CoreContext

```
public class Program :  IDbContextFactory<AuditLogContext>, IDbContextFactory<CoreContext>,IDbContextFactory<LockContext>
```

and the snippet will create migrations for the AuditLogContext.

It's a bit annoying but if you know how to create the migrations it's ok.